# Hard drive usage very high all the time

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance

I have a problem with very high hard drive usage. Computer of my colleague (Sony VAIO) was working very slowly, it had Windows 10 Technical Preview, so I had to reinstall system. I installed Windows 8 and after installing and updating to 8.1, I noticed very high hard drive usage in Task Manager (almost all the time close to 100%). There are different applications using hard drive heavily (service host, antimalware service executable, system), so it is not one application, that I can disable. Internet Explorer, when I navigate to new website, can take most of drive's performance.

I made some tests with Crystal Disk Mark and got poor results (image below). At first I was shocked by these results (this is old HDD and I use SSDs in my computers), but later I tested different another HDD on another computer and results were not far from these ones.

What can I do? Is there anything I can do without taking out hard drive and testing it on another computer?

[image]

Comment: What is the make and model of the HDD? Have you looked up its specifications to see if you can reasonably expect any more speed from it?

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the disk IO (2-3 minutes) and share (onedrive link) the compressed file. Here are the steps: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60